# Where do i write if item is not found, and display an appropriate message?

Tags: java

```
public static void modifyBall(String[] hookPotentialArray, String[] nameBallArray, int[] ballWeightArray, int count) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the ball you would like to modify: ");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (name.compareToIgnoreCase(nameBallArray[i]) == 0) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a new name for the ball: ");
                String ballName = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter a new weight for the ball: ");
                int ballWeight = keyboard.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Please enter a new hook potential for the ball: ");
                String hookPotential = keyboard.next();

                nameBallArray[i] = ballName;
                ballWeightArray[i] = ballWeight;
                hookPotentialArray[i] = hookPotential;

                System.out.println("The ball list has been updated.");
                System.out.println("");


            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should refactor to separate the loop for finding/not finding the ball (or not), and do whatever you need to do with the ball (or error if not found) OUTSIDE the loop.  This helps with readability because more of your lines are less indented, and it helps communicate your intent because most of your code in the loop is only going to be executed once anyway.

```
int ballIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (name.compareToIgnoreCase(nameBallArray[i]) == 0) {
       ballIndex = nameBallArray[i];
       break;
    }
}
if (ballIndex >= 0) {
  // found - do everything using ballIndex
} else {
  // not found - display error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a boolean and set it to true in your if statement that means it's been found.  You could check the boolean after loop to see if it's true or false then display error message if true.

Example:

```
public static void modifyBall(String[] hookPotentialArray, String[] nameBallArray, int[] ballWeightArray, int count) {
boolean found = false; //boolean for if it's found or not
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the name of the ball you would like to modify: ");
String name = keyboard.nextLine();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (name.compareToIgnoreCase(nameBallArray[i]) == 0) {
        found = true; //set boolean if found
        System.out.println("Please enter a new name for the ball: ");
        String ballName = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter a new weight for the ball: ");
        int ballWeight = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter a new hook potential for the ball: ");
        String hookPotential = keyboard.next();

        nameBallArray[i] = ballName;
        ballWeightArray[i] = ballWeight;
        hookPotentialArray[i] = hookPotential;

        System.out.println("The ball list has been updated.");
        System.out.println("");
        break; //break out of loop if item found
    }
}
//check if boolean is false then print error message
if (!found)
{
    System.out.println("There was a problem finding your item.");
}
```

I also added a break at end of if statement to break out of the loop if the item was found(no point in continuing on if the item was already found).

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag variable to 0 before loop. Inside if set it 1. After the loop check if it is still zero. then print appropriate message that no item found.

```
Boolean flag  = false; // before loop

flag = true; //inside if

// After loop
if(!flag)
    System.out.println("Not Found");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public static void modifyBall(String[] hookPotentialArray, String[] nameBallArray, int[] ballWeightArray, int count) {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of the ball you would like to modify: ");
            String name = keyboard.nextLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (name.compareToIgnoreCase(nameBallArray[i]) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a new name for the ball: ");
                    String ballName = keyboard.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Please enter a new weight for the ball: ");
                    int ballWeight = keyboard.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter a new hook potential for the ball: ");
                    String hookPotential = keyboard.next();

                    nameBallArray[i] = ballName;
                    ballWeightArray[i] = ballWeight;
                    hookPotentialArray[i] = hookPotential;

                    System.out.println("The ball list has been updated.");
                    System.out.println("");
                    return;
                }

            }

           System.out.println("ball not found");

}
```